# Blank Page on Wordpress even after reinstal server

Tags: php, wordpress

Title says what is my problem, and it would be great if anyone have any idea. I did everything I found online on this topic, but didn't helped.

I reinstalled vps and put debian instead of ubuntu, but same problem. Reinstalled again, but problem is still here, and affect only wordpress. So apache, php 7.2, mysql, everything is fresh.

Wordpress is just downloaded, and it's not about plugins because it's still not installed. Before reinstalling VPS I tried with plugins, themes, php.ini , wp-config and so on... Any idea what can cause this?

Error log:

[Fri Mar 15 15:07:20.921038 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2210] [client IP:PORT] PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/myweb/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0 [Fri Mar 15 15:07:23.889563 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 2207] [client 185.220.101.27:44328] PHP Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

EDIT: Not affect only wordpress. I just tried to copy simple php file and get error. But I knew it's to php, not to wordpress error.

EDIT 2:

FIXED with : sudo chmod -R 755 ~/site root

Comment: There are too many possible reasons. You need to look into the log files of the server.

Comment: without an adequate question, it will be difficult for anyone to help you. read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry, I forgot to attach. error log is added into question. There is no wordpress error log since VPS is reinstalled. Everything worked fine when I went to the job, when i came home it doesn't worked, so it's hard to say what caused the problem. It affect only wordpress, and even after new download.

Answer (score 0):

When I get errors and saw it's permission problem, it's fixed by:
chmod -R 755 ~/site-root